# Access SignalR Performance Counters in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, signalr

I have trouble accessing the SignalR Performance Counters; How can I access the performance counters for SignalR in .NET Core using C#?
I've sucessfully installed them via

> signalr.exe ipc

But I haven't found any way to access them from my program, which I assume is via the `PerformanceCounter` class.
The documentation is completely unhelpful on how to continue after installing them to using them programmatically.

I assumed I could use them the same way as any performance counter;

```
Process p = <My process>;
PerformanceCounter totalErrorsCounter= new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Message Bus Busy Workers", p.ProcessName);
```

The above results in:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not locate Performance Counter with specified category name 'Process', counter name 'Message Bus Busy Workers'.'
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The documentation is clear, and so is the error - the `Process` category doesn't contain SignalR counters. `Process` is for process metrics like CPU, RAM usage like `% Processor Time`, `% User Time`, `Page Faults/sec`. You'll see all installed categories and counters if you open Performance Monitor on your machine.

Comment: The `signalR.exe` tool is for the *old* SignalR though, not ASP.NET Core SignalR. Are you trying to read counters for an existing ASP.NET SignalR application? Or read metrics for SignalR Core?

Comment: If you want to collect Performance Counters, you could create a "Data Collector Set" 
 in Perf Monitor to collect counters periodically and save them to a file. Your application would only need to pick up new files periodically. You can specify rules that control when data collection stops, what to do if there's not enough space, or move/copy older files to some other folder. The storage target could be a remote file share, allowing quick&easy monitoring of multiple servers

Comment: The documentation may be clear as a reference once you've found somewhere else to get started.

We are using ASP.NET Core SignalR. Are you saying there are no performance counters for ASP.NET Core SignalR?

Do I have to create my own categories in the code? I am interested in monitoring the SignalR Message bus Topics, and related.

Comment: Perf counters are a basic *Windows* feature, that's *far* more powerful than the simple Performance Monitor view. You can find all installed counters in Perf Monitor. You should check it anyway just to see whether they're installed correctly, what the current traffic is etc.  ASP.NET *Core* though is meant to be cross-platform, and Linux has nothing like perf counters - in fact there are multiple libraries like LTTng and DTrace.

Comment: .NET Core uses [EventCounters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventcounter?view=netcore-3.0) to emit performance metrics. .NET Core 3 [added the dotnet-counters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-diagnostics-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) tool to collect and display them in real time. You can [use the tool to list running counters](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/dotnet-counters-instructions.md) and "borrow" the code

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you Panagiotis.
If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't have an answer yet - [there's even an issue about properly documenting the API!](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/19611). The article [.NET Counter internals](https://medium.com/criteo-labs/net-core-counters-internals-how-to-integrate-counters-in-your-monitoring-pipeline-5354cd61b42e) is probably the best I've found until now, explaining how you can use EventPipe and EventPipeClient to *listen* to events.

Comment: You can inspect the source code for [dotnet-counters](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/tree/master/src/Tools/dotnet-counters) - it's a really small tool, but you'll need to understand how the API works

Comment: Well, [adding all SignalR Core counter docs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4826) was pushed to the next version. Searching [the ASP.NET Core repo](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/search?q=eventcounter&type=Code) shows just [one event source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/SignalR/common/Http.Connections/src/Internal/HttpConnectionsEventSource.cs) with events for start/stop connection and timeout.

Comment: The counter names [are defined here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/SignalR/common/Http.Connections/src/Internal/HttpConnectionsEventSource.cs#L84): `connections-started`, `connections-stopped` etc under `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections"`

Comment: Hey, thought I'd get back to you with an update.
We decided to use EventSource, emitting EventCounter for now. We will pipe the Event(s) to our own tracer, and handle the events as they come. A question arised, "how are these different than normal events" -> Performance and filtering were the answers.

TLDR; We implement our own counters, using EventSource as publisher and EventListener as the consumer.